# Laravel Eloquent compare created_at and updated_at

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
TblUserProfile::where('updated_at','>','created_at')->pluck('user_id');
```

**Above query return following**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1854
  #items: []
}
```

**But when i run following query direct to mysql**

```
select `user_id` from `tbl_user_profile` where updated_at > created_at
```

**Gives me result as follow**

[image]

**Is am i doing something wrong in Eloquent?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `whereColumn`

```
TblUserProfile::whereColumn('updated_at','>','created_at')->pluck('user_id');
```